# Error "'JDK version 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"When trying to run a simple titanium project?

Tags: java, titanium, titanium-mobile, javac

I am  new to titanium ,  i installed Titanium and  andriod SDK, i was imported the example provided by the Titanium Site and trying to run it but i am getting the problem **"JDK version 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**"

I really tried hard by fixing the problem by giving  the path in environmental variables but may be  i did some wrong in giving the path or i would have missed out anything ??

**Please Help me Out :-**

1) How can i fix this problem ??

2)What are the various paths which i need to give environmental variables ??

3)What is the exact way of giving the paths ??

Please let me know how can i fix the this issuse .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't set JAVA_HOME. For Titanium development you should set the environment variables

- JAVA_HOME
- add JAVA_HOME\bin to PATH
- ANDROID_SDK

How to set them depends on your machine and i can't guess it since Titanium is running on all mayor platforms. But you'll find all information about that at [Setting up Titanium Studio](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio), [Installation Troubleshooting](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installation_Troubleshooting), [***Environment Variables***](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables) and of course [the compatibility matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix) which contains required versions.

If nothings helps please open Titanium Studio and go to Help -> Titanium Studio -> Run Diagnostic Test and update your question with the results of this test.